# How to control xtick and minor xtick labels

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to draw a graph of data like this:

[image]

With this code:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article} 
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{margin=1in} 

\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[%
title=Wet van Boyle-Mariotte,
major grid style=black,
axis lines=center,
ymin=50,
ymax=270,
axis y discontinuity=crunch,
xmin=0, xmax=21,
xtick={0,1,...,21},
width=\textwidth,
height=15cm,
xlabel={$V$ (ml)},
ylabel={$p$ (kPa)},
%ticks=both,
minor xtick={0,0.2,...,21},
minor ytick={0,2,...,280},
grid=both,
enlarge x limits={upper},
enlarge y limits={upper},
ylabel near ticks,
xlabel near ticks,
]
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

I want (on the x-axe) a black line on 0,1,2,3,... but only a label on 2,4,6... or 0,5,10,... The same with the y-axe.

I know you could achieve this with minor xtick, but I don't want to change the minor xticks, because I need them.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A couple of options:

1. Use `extra` ticks. Remove the ticklabels on both axes, and add `extra x ticks`/`extra y ticks` with labels:

   ```
   xticklabels={},
   yticklabels={},
   extra x ticks={0,2,...,20},
   extra x tick labels={0,2,...,20},
   extra y ticks={60,100,...,280},
   extra y tick labels={60,100,...,280},
   ```
2. Specify the ticklabels manually, adding empty ticks where needed, i.e.

   ```
   xticklabels={0,,2,,4,,6,,8,,10,,12,,14,,16,,18,,20,}
   ```

#### Complete code for first option

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article} 
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{margin=1in} 
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[%
title=Wet van Boyle-Mariotte,
major grid style=black,
axis lines=center,
ymin=50,
ymax=270,
axis y discontinuity=crunch,
xmin=0, xmax=21,
xtick={0,1,...,21},
xticklabels={},
yticklabels={},
extra x ticks={0,2,...,20},
extra x tick labels={0,2,...,20},
extra y ticks={60,100,...,280},
extra y tick labels={60,100,...,280},
width=\textwidth,
height=15cm,
xlabel={$V$ (ml)},
ylabel={$p$ (kPa)},
%ticks=both,
minor xtick={0,0.2,...,21},
minor ytick={0,2,...,280},
grid=both,
enlarge x limits={upper},
enlarge y limits={upper},
ylabel near ticks,
xlabel near ticks,
]
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Is their also an option to make the extra x thicks only 5mm height?

Comment: @Arne `every extra x tick/.append style={tickwidth=5mm}` I guess.